# Create A View, Select a Column As Primary Key

Tags: sql, entity, primary-key, sql-view

I have a long code line to create a view. For Entity framework to work with this view I need a primary key.

How can I select the column as a primary key?

I've tried this;

```
dstchannel,billsec,disposition,accountcode, uniqueid as PRIMARY KEY,cnam, callRateImport.Description, callRateImport.Code, callRateImport.Day FROM callLogImport
LEFT JOIN callRateImport ON
```

uniqueid as PRIMARY KEY.

The other method I tried (to alter view and create primary key) works, but it has to be done before the view is created..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create primary keys on the view itself.

To get around the no primary key issue, you can create a unique column that the entity framework will pick up and use.

`ISNULL(CAST((row_number() OVER (ORDER BY <columnName>)) AS int), 0) AS ID`

So:

```
 SELECT  ISNULL(CAST((row_number() OVER (ORDER BY uniqueid)) AS int), 0) AS ID,  dstchannel,billsec,disposition,accountcode, uniqueid,cnam, callRateImport.Description, callRateImport.Code, callRateImport.Day FROM callLogImport
 LEFT JOIN callRateImport ON ....
```